# CORS and Google Maps Places Autocomplete API calls

Tags: javascript, angular, google-maps-api-3, cors

I am trying to get Angular talk to Google Maps Places Autocomplete API. The problem is that the server doesn't allow CORS calls (it doesn't return an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header) and JSONP calls also seem to be futile as it returns plain JSON and not JSONP, causing a syntax error.

This is what I am currently trying in a service function (`_jsonp` is a `Jsonp` object):

```
return this._jsonp.request(url, { method: 'GET' });
```

And this doesn't work. The response arrives, but Angular crashes because it's not JSONP but JSON.

This is crazy. How on earth can I access this if CORS is disabled and JSONP calls don't work?

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?key=ACCESS_KEY&types=(cities)&input=ber
```

Is there a way to convert a JSON server response into a JSONP data object in the Observable pipeline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The supported way to call the Place Autocomplete API from a web app is [using the Places library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete):

```
<script>
  function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: {lat: -33.8688, lng: 151.2195},
      zoom: 13
    });
    ...
    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT].push(card);
    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
    autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var infowindowContent = document.getElementById('infowindow-content');
    infowindow.setContent(infowindowContent);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      anchorPoint: new google.maps.Point(0, -29)
    });
</script>
<script
  src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places&callback=initMap"
  async defer></script>
```

That way it doesn’t matter that the responses lack the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`  header.

Using the Maps JavaScript API that way—by way of a `script` element to load the library, and then using the `google.maps.Map` and other `google.maps.*` methods—is the only supported way. Google intentionally does not allow doing it by way of requests sent with XHR or the Fetch API.