# Trying to Use Google Places API to Get a List of Cities

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript

I'm trying to use Google Places' API to get a list of cities to display. I was trying to use the Autocomplete feature to get a JSON that I could then parse. But I'm getting the following error:

```
Failed to load 
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?
input=New&types=(cities)&key=AIzaSyBVgF-ywjsdsWx6JMZNR0UlUL8q67wM5m8: 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested 
resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed 
access.
```

I have the following as my API request:

```
searchCities(searchTerm: String) {
  const url = 
       'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?
       input=' + searchTerm +
       '&types=(cities)&key=AIzaSyBVgF-ywjsdsWx6JMZNR0UlUL8q67wM5m8';
return this.http.get(url)
  .map((response: Response) => {
    return response.json();
  });
}
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: what about your google API console, have you added localhost as white list domain?

Comment: How do I do that? I have the following in my server.js file:   res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

Comment: The only supported way to call the Place Autocomplete API from a web app is [using the Places library in the way it’s documented](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete). The code example in the question isn’t using the library in the way the documented — it’s not going to work to call `http.get` on an `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/` endpoint. See the example in the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43443836/angular-cors-jsonp-and-google-maps-http-api-calls/43444274#43444274

Comment: I mean to add config here https://console.developers.google.com/apis/dashboard