# VueJS axios CORS Google Api

Tags: google-maps-api-3, vue.js, cors

I try to get data from API Google Places

```
axios.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=...&key=mykey')
    .then(response => {
      commit('SET_REVIEWS', { list: response.data })
    }, error => {
      console.log(error)
    })
```

And after that i have this error [image]
I know the error with CORS on server side, but what should i do?

Comment: The only supported way to use the Places API endpoints is with the Places Library as outlined in the offcial documentation. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43443836/angular-cors-jsonp-and-google-maps-http-api-calls/43444274#43444274 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44336773/google-maps-api-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-reque/44339169#44339169

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my project I use NuxtJS and I found the solution. 
You have to make a request on the server side (nodeJS), not the client. 
As shown below, the method fetch allows you to do this and it works
https://nuxtjs.org/guide/vuex-store#the-fetch-method

Comment: How can i resolve this trouble on frontend? I don't use server side rendering.

Comment: On frontend you should use places library of Google Maps JavaScript API: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places

Answer (score 0):

Simply create and call a webservice on your own server which in turn calls googles webservice.

The main code of your webservice could look like this, in PHP:

`$url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?key=' . $key . '&placeid=' . $place_id;
echo json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true);`